# What is the Wrong in this Triangulation of the Torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, triangulation

On page 133 of Rotman's *Introduction to Algebraic Topology* it is stated that one requires at least 14 triangles in any triangulation of the torus.

Admittedly, I do not have a very good understanding of triangulations.

From what I understand, the following seems like a perfectly valid triangulation of the torus:

[image: Figure]

What is the mistake in this?

Comment: The 123 and 341 triangles on the left have separate edges (the vertical lines on the left) that share both end points 1 and 3. IIRC that is not allowed in a simplicial complex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The NE and SW blocks both contain triangles with vertices 1,3,4. But these intersect in just the edge 13 and the vertex 4, while the intersection of two simplices in a triangulation must be **a "face" of each** (which might be the empty simplex), not a union of two or more simplices.